# Select Tab getting looped on click

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, semantic-ui

I am trying to display a dropdown where on clicking the input field a http request will be called on to the backend and the data is shown in the dropdown.I have implemented this in the following way using angulalr 2 and semantic ui

```
<div (click)="searchEmployee()" >
<select class="ui search dropdown" id="num" >
<option *ngFor="let data of employeeNameList" value="{{data.num}}">
{{data.employeeName}}({{data.num}})
</option>
</div>
```

The problem with the above implementation is that it is going on a infinite loop of dropdown ,as select tag in enclosed in the div where the function is getting called.Infinite loop as in,if i click on the input button,the data is fetched and displayed and if i click on data ,the dropdown is opened again instead of closing.Please help me resolving the issue

Comment: Search Employee.. What does that do? Just return a list of employees? Why assign to a click handler on a div? Why not in ngInit?

Comment: New to angular world ..basically that function calls rest services and intialise employeenamelist object..

Comment: But does it retrieve all of them? Or use some sort of search criteria to filter?

Comment: It retreives all of them on first click ..

Comment: There are a lot of other tasks on the same page as wel..so i dont wanto call a very big list and waste thr memory .only its needed then i would call it

Comment: The function is getting called only once,as i have given a firsttime flag in d code.But when i click on d dropdown option,and select an option,it again drops doWn instead of closing the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

If i get this right, your problem is that the (click) event handler is on the surrounding div element. That means that any where you click (either the select or the option list), your code to fetch the list will be executed.

**Edit :**

How about moving the (click) handler inside the  element like this and also, add a little hack on the event handler, in order not to call the click event when selecting an option.

Since the change event does not carry coordinates for the click event you can distinguish between those events and act accordingly.

I suppose this is a dirty hack and wouldn't use it on production environments myself, but it is a good starting point to play around with click and change events.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OtVEcH6cBZLoIqtaaha8?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<div>
    <select (click)="searchEmployee($event)" (change)="select()">
        <option *ngFor="let data of employeeNameList" value="{{data.num}}">
        {{data.employeeName}}({{data.num}})
        </option>
    </select>

</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  employeeNameList : any[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  searchEmployee(load){

    if(load.screenX != 0){
      this.employeeNameList = [{employeeName : 'John', num : 1}, {employeeName : 'John2', num : 2}, {employeeName : 'Mary', num : 3}];
    }
  }
  select(){
    //console.log("select");
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Solution 2**
There is another solution also, that works as this. You place an invisible div on top of your select element, and handle the loading there.

This div is added/removed from DOM conditionally, depending on where the user clicks. If the user clicks on the select element, the list is loaded and then the div is removed. 
If the user clicks on an option or outside of the containing div, the overlaying div reappears.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tywGQCxXTxZuIZvAXNOW?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<div id="cont" style="position: relative; display: table; border : 1px solid red;" (blur)="onBlur()">

    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <select #sel (change)="select()">
        <option *ngFor="let data of employeeNameList" value="{{data.num}}">
        {{data.employeeName}}({{data.num}})
        </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="overlay" (click)="searchEmployee($event)" style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display: table-row; z-index: 100; width: 100%; height:100%;"></div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('sel') sel : any;
  name:string;
  employeeNameList : any[] = [];
  overlay : boolean = true;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  searchEmployee(load){

    this.employeeNameList = [{employeeName : 'John', num : 1}, {employeeName : 'John2', num : 2}, {employeeName : 'Mary', num : 3}];
    this.overlay = false;
  }

  onBlur(){
    this.overlay = true;
  }
  select(){
    //console.log("select");
    this.overlay = true;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: if i know it right,you cannot specify click event on select tag.By the way i tried ,it doesnt work

Comment: In fact you can specify a click event on a select tag, only you have to deal with the same problem.. Please look at my updated answer.